# What are differences between 1) training a CNN from whole training set and 2) training from a subset of training set and then whole training set?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, training-data, gradient-descent

I am working on training a segmentation network [U-net](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.06650) on the [LIDC-IDRI](https://wiki.cancerimagingarchive.net/display/Public/LIDC-IDRI) dataset. There are currently two training strategies:

1. Train the model on the whole training set from scratch (40k steps, 180k steps).
2. Train the model on 10% of the whole training set. After convergence (30k steps), continue to train the model on the whole training set (10k steps).

With [Dice coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient) as loss function, which is also used in V-net architecture ([paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.04797)), model trained with Method 2 is always better than that with Method 1. The former can achieve a Dice score of 0.735, while the latter can only reach 0.71.

BTW, my U-net model is implemented in TensorFlow, and the model is trained on NVidia GTX 1080Ti

Could anyone give some explanation or references. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I read your answer and decided to try it, as it was fairly easy, as I've also been training Vnets on LIDC-IDRI. Usually I train on the whole dataset from the beginning. Option 2) gave faster boost in dice, however, soon it fell to 2%  on validation and even after enabling the network to learn the whole dataset it did not recover, training dice. of course, was increasing. Seems my 10% of dataset were not quite representative and it badly overfit.